# Im trying to increase the data_width using resize and then make then change the MSB of the new value

Tags: vhdl

im making a signed adder and i need to increase the data_width and then take the MSB of the input and assign it to the MSB of the longer Variable for example with a 4 bit input of 1010 i have turned it to z1010 but i need to 11010 and for a 0110 i can change it to z0110 and need to make it 00110

```vhdl
    port (
        A   : in  std_logic_vector ((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        B   : in  std_logic_vector  ((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
        SUM : out std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH downto 0) 

    );

end entity;



architecture v1 of DeMUX is

        -- start    
begin

DeMUX : process (A, B) is

    variable AA :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    variable BB :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH-1) downto 0);
    variable CA :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH) downto 0);
    variable SUMMER :  std_logic_vector(((DATA_WIDTH-1)) downto 0);
    variable SUMMER2 :  std_logic_vector((DATA_WIDTH) downto 0);

begin   
-- so the sum is the Xor of A and B. however you also need to include the carry bit as it might not fit this means 
--you and A and B to find C if MSB of AB = 0 & C= 1 add 1 to sum                                



            AA := A;    
            BB := B;

            SUM <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(AA), SUM'length));    
            SUM <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(BB), SUM'length));

        AA(DATA_WIDTH)  := A(DATA_WIDTH);
        BB(DATA_WIDTH)  := B(DATA_WIDTH);
```

i receive an error of, index value 4 is outside the range (3 down to 0) of object "a"
any advice is welcome

Comment: Your code example is neither minimal nor complete. Provide a [mcve], code that analyzes or elaborates and provides a specific error from a VHDL tool which would indicate a line number. Note indexed names  AA(DATA_WIDTH), A(DATA_WIDTH),  BB(DATA_WIDTH) and B(DATA_WIDTH) all have indexes outside the range of their prefix object declarations (DATA_WIDTH - 1 downto 0). If DATA_WIDTH is a generic the error(s) would show up after elaboration.

Answer (score 0):

You can't declare a fixed size output :

```
 SUM : out std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH downto 0)
```

and affect it with variable size signals :

```
SUM <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(AA), SUM'length));    
SUM <= std_logic_vector(resize(signed(BB), SUM'length));
```

To do things properly, affect you signal SUM with a fixed size, whether the size of the addition is DATA_WIDTH or DATA_WIDTH + 1

SLP

Comment: Yes you can. More characters.